# Python regex search and grouping

Tags: python, regex

```
04:38:06.151 [http-bio-5443-exec-8] INFO  A.g.r.q.r.flex.RubixService   - [NO-ID] [Mar 26, 2014 04:38:06 UTC] -     [5a-y2-24C363B223F1CB534B8DCA5693ADF2E9] --0->servAggregateMultiple:61224380032:[[{"responseMeasures":    ["SubscriberCnt","UpBytes","DownBytes","SessionCount","SubscriberPercentage","UpBytesPercentage","DownBytesPercentage","SessionCountPercentage"]
"sortProperty":"SubscriberCnt"
```

I have this data in a text file. I want to perform search and find for responseMeasures which is there is this chunk of data. If it finds it, I want to store everything after that that is:-

```
["SubscriberCnt","UpBytes","DownBytes","SessionCount","SubscriberPercentage","UpBytesPercentage","DownBytesPercentage","SessionCountPercentage"]
```

I want to store it as a group in a variable. Similary I want the same to find sortProperty and store "SubscriberCnt" in a variable as a group.

Here is my code snippet:-

```
import re
fo = open("data.txt", "r")
data = fo.readlines()
for n in data:
        matchMeasure = re.search("responseMeasures:", n)
        if matchMeasure:
                measureData =  matchMeasure.groups()
                print "Measures are" +  str(measureData)
        matchDimension = re.search("sortProperty", n)
        if matchSort:
                sortData = matchSort.groups()
                print "Group by" + str(sortData)
```

This code might not be the best way to do it but only to show what I am looking for.

The expected output I want:-

```
Meausres are:-
SubscriberCnt
UpBytes
DownBytes
SessionCount
SubscriberPercentage
UpBytesPercentage
DownBytesPercentage
SessionCountPercentage"
Group by SubscriberCnt
```

Comment: Hi, I was wondering... did you figure out how to solve your last problem? You deleted your question and I can't comment there anymore =/

Comment: sorry, I undeleted it. Yes I did, thats why I accepted the anser, Actually I m facing alot of other problems too. Just wondering If u can help me out?oh sorry, u meant the last question, nope Im facing alot of problems in it. Can u come on some chat or something so that I can tell u what exactly im looking for?

Comment: I was talking about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22678611/1578604). I think I have a solution for that question. And I don't know if I can help with all of them, but I could try my best :)

Comment: Maybe [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46067/tcl)? there's barely anyone there anyway xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by using re.findall

```
with open('data.txt','r') as f:

    first_filter = re.findall(r"[\w']+", f.read())
    measures = first_filter[first_filter.index('responseMeasures')+1:first_filter.index('sortProperty')]
    sortby = first_filter[first_filter.index('sortProperty')+1::]

    for measure in measures:
        print measure

    print "Group by:"

    for sort_type in sortby:
        print sort_type
```